# preencher campo select javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, bootstrap-3

Olá, preciso preencher um campo select com o retorno dessa função, nesse exemplo, a variável RES retorna:

```
<option value="">setor 1</option>
```

exatamente isso, preciso que se torne uma das opções do meu campo select, mas nada acontece, estou tentando assim:

```
$('#cSetor').html(res);
```

onde cSetor é o ID do meu campo select

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cSecretaria').on('change', function() {
        $.post('_require/_jp/jpcarregasetor.php', {
            id_sec: document.getElementById("cSecretaria").value,
        }, function(res) {
            $('#cSetor').html(res);
        })
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="cSetor">Setor pertencente</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="--" name="tSetor" id="cSetor">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: O que dá `console.log(res)`  colocado no lugar de `$('#cSetor').html(res);`?

Comment: não acontece nada

Comment: Sabes onde vêr o resultado de `console.log`? Senão usa alert.

Comment: coloquei alert(console.log(res));
o resultado do alert foi: undefined

Comment: O que queria dizer era `alert(res);`

Comment: ah, desculpe, o resultado é um código option pro select, bem certinho:   < option > teste < option >

Comment: Ok, isso é bom. Então e se fizeres `$('#cSetor').append(res).selectpicker('refresh');` funciona?

Comment: funcionou, mas tem um problema, esse select #cSetor depende de qual eu escolher em um anterior, e a cada vez que eu escolho uma opção no anterior, atualiza o select #cSetor, mas do modo que tu me mostrou ele vai adicionando novas opções ao #cSetor, quando deveria deletar as anteriores e carregar tudo novamente, entendeu ?

Comment: Juntei resposta com as duas opções.

Comment: oi, tem algum outro modo? pq do jeito que tu me mostrou, a cada vez que clico é adicionada mais uma opção do meu select, e eu não quero isso

Comment: Marcelo: sim, como coloquei na resposta, viste? usando o `.html()` mas chamando o `.selectpicker('refresh');` também. -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129553/129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vejo que estás a utilizar o select do Boostrap, então para qualquer mudança que faças tens de chamar o método `.selectpicker('refresh');` para ele aplicar as mudanças.

Se quiseres substiruir o HTML podes usar

```
$('#cSetor').html(res).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Se quiseres acrescentar HTML podes usar

```
$('#cSetor').append(res).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Desculpa, tava cuidando os comentários ali em cima, deu certo agora usando o .html(), valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Troque o "html" por "append":

```
$('#cSetor').append(res);
```

Comment: já tentei, não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Troque value="", por value=''

Confirme também se o dataType do ajax esta como HTML

Comment: Que diferênça faz se `""` ou `''`? usando `value=` vai apagar o value e não buscá-lo...