# preencher campo select ao abrir página javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Oi, eu já havia recebido uma grande ajuda quando precisei que um campo select fosse preenchido automaticamente, nesse post aqui: [preencher campo select javascript / jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129551/preencher-campo-select-javascript-jquery?noredirect=1#comment269847_129551)

está funcionando perfeita mente, mas agora preciso que, ao abrir uma página onde o campo select já venha preenchido, o segundo campo select preencha automaticamente também, mas ele só está preenchendo no momento que eu clico e seleciono algo no meu primeiro campo select.

Aqui o código javascript que preenche o select (preciso que ele preencha quando abrir a página, sendo que vai vir do banco um valor "selected" pra ele, e não apenas quando eu seleciono algo)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cSecretaria').on('change', function(){
    $.post('http://siscpd.com/_require/_jp/jpcarregasetor.php',
        {
            id_sec: document.getElementById("cSecretaria").value,
        },
        function (res) {
            $('#cSetor').html(res).selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    )
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de utilizar o parametro `val` assim

```
$('select').selectpicker('val', 'valorDoOption');
```

Esse `select` do Boostrap tem os próprios métodos, [dá uma olhada à documentação](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval).

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k2nsrjn4/

Answer (score 0):

Use o atributo selected.

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```